# Feature Selection in multi variate time series classification

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I have a time series data with `9` variables. I find 4 feature out of it. 
For example i calculate `np.mean(), np.std(), np.var(), np.ptp()` Now my columns extend to `36` variables from `9` variables.

The feature selection method available in `sklearn` work for univariate data. So when i apply these method to multivariate data , they would not find whether `np.mean()` is a better feature than `np.std()`. They will simply find best variables out of 36 variables.

So i want to know, what should be the correct approach to deal with multivariate data.

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize to make sure I understood your problem first. You have time series data of 9 variables, means you have 9 channels of length `L`, so a matrix of shape `L x 9`, correct? Now you calculate your 4 features on every channel making it a matrix of shape `L x 36`.

What e.g. `sklearn.selectKBest` does is to select the k best features of your 36 feature vectors. So for example if `k = 18` you'll get a matrix of shape `L x 18` after transformation. It selects the 18 best features.

Can you elaborate a little bit more on your problem and what you like to achieve? Possibly with some code?

**Edit:**

Possible solution to see what features were selected:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
# X.shape = (1797, 64)
kbest = SelectKBest(chi2, k=20)
kbest.fit(X, y)
X_new = kbest.transform(X)
# X_new.shape = (1797, 20)
selected_features = kbest.get_support()
# Returns a mask of X.shape[1]
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
       False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
       False])
```

Now you just need to keep in mind which features correspond to the indices masked with `true`.

Inspired by sklearn-documentation for `SelectKBest` (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest)

Comment: you understand exactly what i want to say. Let me elobarte it further. In case of univariate data, what i want to find which one of 4 feature work well. Suppose if K=2, it return me two feature. Let say these two features are `mean` and `std`. But in case of of multivariate it return me a part of these two features. It does return me two feature.  
Making it more consise, would not, it should return `2 feature x 9=18`  so i can know which two feature work well